# How to display CPT archives?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

I have a site where we merged two blogs, one in the normal blog and one in a custom post type. Everything is fine except we cannot get the monthly archives to display for the CPT. We've tried a variety of plugin, and no matter what we get the list of regular blog posts and we get redirected there. We have has_archive enabled, so what are we missing? I never tried to merge two blogs so its a bit of a challenge.

On the regular blog though too, the first archive shows 26 posts, but when you go to it, nothing shows. Ever other month is fine though?

[Problem Blog](http://kieffers.satoristaging.com/kieffers-cooking-blog/)

[Regular Blog](http://kieffers.satoristaging.com/kieffers-appliance-blog/)

Comment: Custom post types don't have date archives by default, though there is some hackery that can be done to add them, it's been answered before on this site somewhere

Comment: Also your pagination issue is something you should ask as a separate question, but I can tell you it's because it isn't a post archive, it's a page with a page template. Is there any reason a multisite install with 3 sites ( 1 for the main site, 2 for each blog ) couldn't have done this?

Answer (score 2):

Is the cooking blog under a CPT? In your CPT definition there is an argument to enable archives.

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type under "has_archive"

That value will need to be set to true. After that, the CPT will be available at example.com/cpt-slug-here

If you want to change that, you can set the value by overriding the `rewrite` argument. See the link above for more info. In this case, it would be `'kieffers-cooking-blog'`